# Python function vs partial - Scipy doesn't like partials

Tags: python, function, scipy, partial

So I was reading the `curve_fit` [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). `curve_fit` takes the function to be fitted as its first argument. I slightly modified the example code in order to give it a partial as the first argument:

```
In:

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def func( t, x , a, b, c): # I added a dummy variable t so that I can apply partials later
    return a*np.exp(-b*x) + c + t 
func = partial( func, 0 ) # use of partial to remove the dummy variable
x = np.linspace(0,4,50)
y = func(x, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5)
yn = y + 0.2*np.random.normal(size=len(x))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, yn) # curve_fit gets a partial instead of a Python function

Out:
TypeError: <functools.partial object at 0x104551c58> is not a Python function
```

Ah, that's disappointing. I guess I will use a `lambda` next time.
Anyway, what is the problem here? What is it that a function can do and that a partial cannot do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`curve_fit` uses [`getargspec`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) from the standard library [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) to determine the arguments to the function.  Unfortunately, `getargspec` doesn't handle a partial:

```
In [31]: from inspect import getargspec

In [32]: from functools import partial

In [33]: def func(t, x, a, b, c):
   ....:     return a*np.exp(-b*x) + c + t
   ....: 

In [34]: pfunc = partial(func, 0)
```

`getargspec(func)` works fine.

```
In [35]: getargspec(func)
Out[35]: ArgSpec(args=['t', 'x', 'a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

But `getargspec` doesn't handle a partial function:

```
In [36]: getargspec(pfunc)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-3fb5eaea7c94> in <module>()
----> 1 getargspec(pfunc)

/Users/warren/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/inspect.pyc in getargspec(func)
    814         func = func.im_func
    815     if not isfunction(func):
--> 816         raise TypeError('{!r} is not a Python function'.format(func))
    817     args, varargs, varkw = getargs(func.func_code)
    818     return ArgSpec(args, varargs, varkw, func.func_defaults)

TypeError: <functools.partial object at 0x107ec6d08> is not a Python function
```

Comment: tracing the code a bit further, it's question of whether `isinstance(func, types.FunctionType)` or not.  `type(pfunc)` is `functools.partial`.

Comment: `curvefit` just uses `getargspec` to determine the `len(args)`.  In this case that would 5 for `func`, and 5-1 for `pfunc`, i.e. `len(getargspec(pfunc.func)[0])-len(pfunc.args)`.  A custom `curvefit` using this calculation might work.

Answer (score 2):

Update:
getargspec handles partial functions in python 3.5 and 3.6 so using partial with curve_fit works.  I don't have older versions of python3 installed so I can't check them.

python 3.6, scipy 0.18.1, numpy 1.12.0

```
import numpy as np
from functools import partial
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(t, x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x) + c + t

x = np.linspace(0,4,50)

pfunc = partial(func, 0.0)
y = pfunc(x, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(pfunc, x, y)
print(popt, y[0:2])

pfunc = partial(func, 100.0)
y = pfunc(x, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(pfunc, x, y)
print(popt, y[0:2])

[ 2.5  1.3  0.5] [   3.       2.7482863]
[ 2.5  1.3  0.5] [ 103.     102.7482863]
```